# How to submit Spark job to AWS EC2 cluster?

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-ec2

I am new to AWS EC2 and need to know how I can submit my Spark job to AWS EC2 spark cluster. Like in azure we can directly submit the job through IntelliJ idea with azure plugin.

Answer (score 0):

You can submit a spark job easily through spark-submit command. Refer http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/submitting-applications.html

Answer (score 0):

Options: 
1) login to master or other driver gateway node and use spark-submit to submit the job through YARN/media/etc

2) Use spark submit cluster deploy mode from any machine with sufficient ports and firewall access (may require configuration, such as client config files from Cloudera manager for CDH cluster)

3) Use a server setup like Livy (open source through Cloudera, and MS Azure HDinsights uses and contributes to it) or maybe thrift server. Livy (Livy.io) is a nice simple REST service that also has language APIs for Scala/Java to make it extra easy to submit jobs (and run interactive persisted sessions!)